# Magento 2: Header & Footer Not Displaying in Contact Us Email

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

I have created custom module and override contact-us email template. Also, I have changed contact us email type and set **html**. It's working perfectly. But the problem is when I received email, email header and footer are missing. Logo is not displayed.

Magento version 2.1.7

Here is my code.

**module.xml** should be [Vendor/RewriteContact/etc/module.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_RewriteContact" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Contact"/>
        </sequence>
    </module> </config>
```

**email_templates.xml** should be [Vendor/RewriteContact/etc/email_templates.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="contact_email_email_template" label="Contact Form" file="submitted_form.html" type="html" module="Vendor_RewriteContact" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

**submitted_form.html** should be [Vendor/RewriteContact/view/frontend/email/submitted_form.html]

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject {{trans "Contact Form"}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var data.comment":"Comment",
"var data.email":"Sender Email",
"var data.name":"Sender Name",
"var data.telephone":"Sender Telephone",
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/footer_template\"":"Email Footer Template",
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/header_template\"":"Email Header Template"
} @-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
{{trans "Phone Number: %telephone" telephone=$data.telephone}}

{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Comment: did you run all this commands in order??. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`, `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: Yes, I have run all command

Comment: Hi @Vishal Bariya, did you find solution of you problem. I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Mohit Kumar Arora, I have try many But can't find solution.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not a proper solution; after too much debugging, I fixed the issue by the below process:

- Create a new template for Contact Us email from **Marketing > Email Templates**.
- Check the **preview** of the template and open page source of the template preview page.
- Copy **HTML source** of the portion in which email template content is being shown.
- Put the copied source into email template and replace the dynamic content with respective variables again.
- Save the template and apply it from **Stores > Configuration > General (Contacts) > Email Options**.

Now try it from the frontend. I hope it would help you also.